# how to recall a jquery function after html change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out why my function stopped working after I changed html code.

I have a div:

```
<div class="float">
<div class="box" data-speed="3" data-direction="X"><h1>Hola</h1></div>
<div class="box" data-speed="2" data-direction="X"><h1>chau</h1></div>
</div>
```

And the jquery code :

```
$(function() {
    $('.box').moveIt();
});    
//move elements in different speeds
$.fn.moveIt = function () {
    var win = $(window);
    var it = $(this);
    var instances = [];

    $(this).each(function (){
        instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
    });

    $('.parallax').on('scroll', function() {
        instances.forEach(function(inst){
            var wrap = inst.el.parents('.float');
            var scrol = win.scrollTop()-wrap.offset().top;
            inst.update(scrol);
        });
    });

}

var moveItItem = function(el){
  this.el = $(el);
  this.speed = parseInt(this.el.attr('data-scroll-speed'));
  this.direction = this.el.attr('data-direction');
};

moveItItem.prototype.update = function(scrollTop){
    var pos = scrollTop / this.speed;
    this.el.css('transform', 'translate'+this.direction+'(' + -pos + 'px)');
};
```

ok until here everything working, when I scroll the elements `.box` translate accordingly.

But now I am trying to modify the html in class `.float` after an ajax call

```
//after ajax
$.ajax({
    url: 'do_content.php'
}).done(function(result) {
    //result = <div class="box" data-speed="3" data-direction="X"><h1>Como estas?</h1></div>
    $('.float').html(result);
});
```

After when I fired the scroll again the function appear to look broken and I got this message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at http://localhost/ophelia/public/js/control.js?v=1487219951:197:45
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/ophelia/public/js/control.js?v=1487219951:195:13)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (http://localhost/ophelia/public/utilities/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10315)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (http://localhost/ophelia/public/utilities/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8342)
```

I understand that this message appear only if I change the elements with class `.box` (I tried to change the only the `h1` and it doesnt break but I want to change everything to change also the speeds)

How can I re-fire the function?

I tried to call it again with `$('.box').moveIt();` but still getting the same error

I know is a long question but didnt find another way to explain my problem

Comment: Can you post the code for your ajax function as well, please?

Comment: When you tried to re-call the function, did you put the call inside the `done()` method, or outside of it, just after the whole ajax method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed (but maybe not so clear), the problem is that you attach an event handler using elements existing in the page in a certain moment of time (I think to the `instances` var). Then you substitute them, but your handler is already set on scroll for element with class .parallax and already registered using that instance of `instances` and so on.

One way is to rewrite your code using delegate methods.

From http://api.jquery.com/on/

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time
>
> An event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one
>   element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level
>   (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
 $( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {

  console.log( $( this ).text() );

});
```

But It may be complex as you should deeply restructure your code.

Otherwise you could rewrite your function as follows (sorry I can't make fiddles)

```
$(function() {
    $('.parallax').moveIt();
});  

//move elements in different speeds
$.fn.moveIt = function () {
    var win = $(window);
    var it = $(this);
//REMOVED
//var instances = [];


//    $(this).each(function (){
//        instances.push(new moveItItem($(this)));
//    });

    $(this).on('scroll', function() {
        $('.box').each(function(){
            var inst=new moveItItem($(this));
            var wrap = inst.el.parents('.float');
            var scrol = win.scrollTop()-wrap.offset().top;
            inst.update(scrol);
        });
    });

 }

...... and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the html element tied to the listener has been replaced..
Like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjoriginal/11tgf6kL) here.. The alert works but after the html is changed, it doesn't. This is because the old element has been replaced by the new element.

You can use the `on` function in jQuery to get past this like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjoriginal/j9ra9Lm3/)

Answer (score 1):

you could bind event on `div.float` and go through `element.children` to move every `.box`

Comment: true! just gonna mark the other questions as right because has the example :) thanks